ClassNotFoundException On IL2CPP AAB (Android) Build
We have a game that we have been developing for Android for a long time. We removed all 3rd party plugins because we received a build error.
After this stage, we started to encounter errors and tried some of the methods below again. Our game works without any problems when we get the APK build. However, when we get the App Bundle (Google Play, AAB) build, it gives the following error at the beginning and the application does not open at all.
Here are a few things we tried:

We tried separately by including and excluding the GooglePlayPlugins*1 plugin in the application,
We tried by installing and removing the Firebase SDK,
We tried by installing and removing the Facebook SDK,
We tried multiple EDM4U versions,
But unfortunately, we could not reach any result.

We thought that we should get help from more professional people for a more detailed debugging or to reach a solution.
We are waiting for your help.
Error code: (FULL CODE HERE: https://justpaste.it/f8exr)
art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] Pending exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task
art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at java.lang.Class libcore.reflect.InternalNames.getClass(java.lang.ClassLoader, java.lang.String) (InternalNames.java:55)
art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at java.lang.Class java.lang.Class.getDexCacheType(com.android.dex.Dex, int) (Class.java:2551)
art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at java.lang.Class java.lang.reflect.Method.getReturnType() (Method.java:150)
art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at void com.unity3d.player.PlayAssetDeliveryUnityWrapper.<init>(android.content.Context) ((null):-1)
art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at com.unity3d.player.PlayAssetDeliveryUnityWrapper com.unity3d.player.PlayAssetDeliveryUnityWrapper.init(android.content.Context) ((null):-1)
art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at boolean com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.nativeRender() ((null):-2)
art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at boolean com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.-$$Nest$mnativeRender(com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer) ((null):-1)
art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at boolean com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$F$a.handleMessage(android.os.Message) ((null):-1)
art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:98)
art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:154)
art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at void com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$F.run() ((null):-1)
art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.bearbite.hon-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.bearbite.hon-1/lib/arm, /data/app/com.bearbite.hon-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:380)
art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at java.lang.Class libcore.reflect.InternalNames.getClass(java.lang.ClassLoader, java.lang.String) (InternalNames.java:53)
art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at java.lang.Class java.lang.Class.getDexCacheType(com.android.dex.Dex, int) (Class.java:2551)
art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at java.lang.Class java.lang.reflect.Method.getReturnType() (Method.java:150)
art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at void com.unity3d.player.PlayAssetDeliveryUnityWrapper.<init>(android.content.Context) ((null):-1)
art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at com.unity3d.player.PlayAssetDeliveryUnityWrapper com.unity3d.player.PlayAssetDeliveryUnityWrapper.init(android.content.Context) ((null):-1)
art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at boolean com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.nativeRender() ((null):-2)
art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at boolean com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.-$$Nest$mnativeRender(com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer) ((null):-1)
art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at boolean com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$F$a.handleMessage(android.os.Message) ((null):-1)
art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:98)
art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:154)
art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at void com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$F.run() ((null):-1)


*1

We tried separately by including and excluding the GooglePlayPlugins*1 plugin in the application,
We tried by installing and removing the Firebase SDK,
We tried by installing and removing the Facebook SDK,
We tried multiple EDM4U versions


Have you checked your R8 configuration?

Hello,
First of all, thank you for your response. Yes, there is no problem there either.
